# Python: int to binary stream element?

Tags: python, binary

If you have a `int` and you wish to convert it to a single char string you can use the function `chr()`

Is there a way to convert an int to a single char binary stream?

e.g:

```
>>> something(97)
b'a'
```

What is the something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.x:

```
>>> bytes([97])
b'a'
```

Comment: yeah, whoops, fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
bytes(chr(97))
```

Comment: and that won't fail if given any number 0-255?

Comment: it won't fail, this one-liner runs fine: `for x in range(256): bytes(chr(x))`